# Radio alterar valor de input Time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando fazer com que o rádio selecionado altere o valor padrão de um input time verifiquei que com javascript ou jquery consigo mas não estou conseguindo fazer da forma que preciso.

Tenho 3 Radio e 1 input time.

Caso o radio selecionado seja saída,deve conter o valor padrão 17:30
Caso seja entrada o valor padrão deve ser 08:00
caso seja folga deve conter valor padrão de 00:00(essa opção deve ficar bloqueada para alteração)

```js
var campoHora = document.querySelector('input[type="time"]');
    case '1':
                document.getElementById( 'tipo' ).innerHTML = 'entrada';
                document.campoHora.value="10:00";
                break;
                case '2':
                document.getElementById( 'tipo' ).innerHTML = 'saida';
                document.campoHora.value= "12:00";
                break;
```

```html
<div class="container"> <!-- 3 + 6 + 3 = 12 -->
    <div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">DATA</font>
    </br>
    <div id="campos">
    <input id="date" type="date">
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">SAÍDA/ENTRADA/FOLGA</font>
    <div id="time">
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" id="entrada" value = "entrada" style="margin-top:15px;"/> Entrada
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" id="saida" value = "saida" style="margin-top:15px;" /> Saída
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" id="folga" value = "folga" style="margin-top:15px;" /> Folga
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">Horas</font></br>
    <input id="time" name="time" type="time" value="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar também o código JS que tentou fazer e descrever o resultado obtido?

Comment: Editado,ele não retorna nada nesse caso.

Comment: Tem certeza que copiou o código certo? O JS que colocou está bem estranho, com a sintaxe bastante errada; há vários `case` perdido, sem ter as devidas estruturas de controle. Se esse é realmente o código que tentou fazer, recomendo fortemente que revise a sintaxe da linguagem antes de continuar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possível forma de fazer isso seria utilizando o método `change` do `jQuery`, conforme demonstrado abaixo:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.entradasaidafolga').change(function(){
     var campo = $(this).val();
     if (campo == "entrada"){ 
         $("#horas").val('08:00');
         $("#horas").attr('readonly', false);
     }
     else if (campo == "saida"){ 
         $("#horas").val('17:30');
         $("#horas").attr('readonly', false);
     } 
     else if (campo == "folga"){ 
         $("#horas").val('00:00');
         $("#horas").attr('readonly', true);
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">DATA</font>
    <br>
    <div id="campos">
       <input id="date" type="date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">SAÍDA/ENTRADA/FOLGA</font>
    <div id="time">
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" class="entradasaidafolga" id="entrada" value = "entrada" style="margin-top:15px;"/> Entrada
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" class="entradasaidafolga" id="saida" value = "saida" style="margin-top:15px;" /> Saída
        <input type = "radio" name = "tipo" class="entradasaidafolga" id="folga" value = "folga" style="margin-top:15px;" /> Folga
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><font color="red">Horas</font><br>
       <input id="horas" name="time" type="time" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado,funcionou.

Comment: @Noscin Depois só marca a pergunta como respondida (clicar no 'v' ao lado da resposta), para que a comunidade saiba que o seu problema já foi resolvido e a dúvida sanada.